# Cannot Open .txt file to read integers

Tags: java, file

i am having an issue opening a file and getting my program to read the integers in the file. In the code below, to get my car data i can either have it randomly generated to get my duration time for a car, and the chance that a car arrives. Or read integers from a file. The file is already given by our professor and her is what is in the file:

```
37259 9819
46363 22666
46161 79934
5693 31416
91459 8272
72792 9493
83603 8372
77842 64629
84792 747
1299 178
```

Apparently I am unable to open the file even using the absolute path, or data = dataFile.nextInt() isn't the correct format to use. Any help would be appreciated i am absolutely stumped on this part, my whole program works but files are my Achilles heel.

```
 if (dataSource == 1) {

        System.out.printf("Enter a filename \t :");
        String aName = input.next();
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(aName);



                    try {
                        dataFile = new Scanner(file);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Can't open file");
                    }

    } else {
        dataRandom = new Random();
        System.out.println("Is Random Active");
    }
    input.close();
}

private void getCarData() {

    if (dataSource == 1) {
        int data1;
        int data2;
        data1 = dataFile.nextInt();
        data2 = dataFile.nextInt();
        anyNewArrival = (((data1%100) + 1) <= chancesOfArrival);  
        serviceDuration = (data2%maxDuration) + 1;
        System.out.println("New Car has arrived with Duration Time: " + serviceDuration);//}
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so, what's the exception, and on what line does it occur?

Comment: says"Can't open file",Can't open file

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PJ3.GasStationSimulator.getCarData(GasStationSimulator.java:112)
 at PJ3.GasStationSimulator.doSimulation(GasStationSimulator.java:142)
 at PJ3.GasStationSimulator.main(GasStationSimulator.java:297)
Java Result: 1  Line112 is data1 = dataFile.nextInt();

Comment: Replace the `System.out.println("Can't open file");` with `e.printStackTrace()` and see if you get a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\**** (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) I placed in the **** where my name is, it then points to line 112 and 95 which are dataFile = new Scanner(file); and data1 = dataFile.nextInt(); thanks and sorry not used to the forum/comment format

Comment: Are you running from an IDE like netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: I am using netbeans yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running from Netbeans or Ecplise, you can use the relative path **"text.txt"** And make sure your file structure is something like this

```
ProjectRoot
         src
         build
         text.txt
```

Comment: Ah ok, i moved the file from my documents to the netbeans project folder and I am able to open it just typing in DataFile(name of file). Still why was i unable to open the file if it was in my document folder?